# Modelicac: algorithm or function clause causes Error

Tags: scilab, modelica

I am using Modelica in Scilab 5.5.1 and I want to use an algorithm clause to calculate the varable lambda in every step

I wrote the calculation in a function:

```
function lambda_calc
        input Real K;
        output Real lambda;
    algorithm
        lambda := 3*K;   
end lambda_calc;
```

and when I try to call `lambda = lambda_calc( 1 );` I get this error:

```
-------Modelica translator error message:-----
---------------------------------------------------
Translator v1.2 for Scicos from Modelica 2.x to flat Modelica
Copyright (C)
2005-2007 Imagine,
2007-2008 LMS-Imagine
Build date is not known (2008-04-01).
---------------------------------------------------
ERROR 2000:
--- Use of not yet implemented feature: Use of class reference in expression is allowed only for external function call
--- Execution step: Code generation for class "lambda_calc"
```

I tried various places for the function. I also put just the algorithm in the regarded model. All lead to similar errors. I doubt that the possibility of algorithms and functions is not yet implemented. Does anyone see my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

According to [official modelica webside](https://www.modelica.org/tools) modelicac just contains a subset of modelica. It can solve implicit equations but algorithms or functions are not mentioned. Therefore I guess that it is really not implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You could try some other Modelica compiler. Are you bound to Scilab?

Comment: Scilab wants to switch their internal Modelica compiler to OpenModelica but it will take a while.

Comment: My aim is a soft real-time simulation with the possibility to change parameters ( for example with a silder)  druing the simulation. My modelling is done in Modelica. Is there a good (and free) alternative to do the simulation? My workaround was to express the algorithm in equations.